# How can I specifically improve my webdesign?

Tags: website-design

My website is www.strongape.com and I'm looking to improve my design.  I don't know where to start.  Are there other forums I should visit for advice?

Comment: I'm gonna say this question is too localized, and it should be rephrased to how any webdesigner can improve their webdesign, not just _"how can I improve this specific website's design"_ --esp. since 2 of the answers are already worded in that vein.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: I see you're asking for specific advice about your OWN website...not "design" in general. My mistake. Regardless, my original answer should be of some use as well.

Just...look around! Monkey see, monkey learn, monkey do. When I'm not designing a website, I'm always on the lookout for sites that make me go "wow", or small little features that I really like.

Forums can help you learn a technique, but they can't help you actually get better. [CrowdSPRING](http://www.crowdspring.com) and [99Designs](http://www.99designs.com) are both freelance websites where clients post projects and then designers basically battle it out to create a design for the client. In projects that are not "private", you'll be able to see all of the different entries. Even when I'm not participating in a project, I love looking at the galleries of projects to see how different designers approached creating a design solution for a specific need, be it a logo, poster, or and entire website. These will show you different techniques and give you some ideas for how to approach a design.

If, however, you want specific tutorials, [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com) boasts a fabulous and very comprehensive database of video tutorials for just about any piece of software you can imagine. I have found it to be extremely useful.

I urge you to use a combination of these things to get better. There's no *right* way to do it. Just practice, research, and practice some more. Oh, and have fun :)

Comment: Excellent, I haven't thought of looking at freelance websites for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously saying it is not looking very good you need to work on font size, design, color  everything, to make it appealing. Do not use yellow color as your button, make some soothing buttons which look good with your whole color scheme. Do remove that green background, you need a very good CSS because your background is repeating till the last edge and it is not at all looking good.

Also IE don't support the way you are using gradient. Get a good looking gradient image to work on all browsers.

As for advice you should see by yourself, look at different web sites and what makes them so appealing to try to cover all those things in your site.

Here are some sites for design inspiration :

1. [30 sources to get your web design inspiration](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/30-sources-to-get-your-web-design-inspiration/)
2. [Open web design](http://www.openwebdesign.org/)
3. [Template box](http://www.templatesbox.com/templates.htm)
4. [27 best web layout](http://dzineblog.com/2009/01/27-best-photoshop-web-layout-design-tutorials-part-2.html)

As you are using spiral in your website it should be simple and effective check 5) and try to make some changes if possible and I bet you'll come with something very appealing all you have to look, catch and use and your done.

PS : I am also not good in design I always see and try to make them more appealing with some efforts . So don't be afraid of creating anything just do whatever you want to in your design.

Give a read to this : [How to Drastically Improve Your Designs](http://designinformer.com/how-to-drastically-improve-your-designs/)

Answer (score 0):

**Find inspiration**

I would recommend looking over some gallery websites that feature some top web designs for inspiration:

- Dribbble - http://dribbble.com/
- Ads of the world: http://adsoftheworld.com/
- CSS Beauty - http://cssbeauty.com/

**Start Sketching**

Improve your pre-visualization skills. After reviewing some other peoples work find what you like about them and start sketching out thumbs and do studies on figure out what works.

Keep a sketchbook around and sketch ideas.

**Practice**

Offer to design websites for pro-bono. There are many non-profit organizations that will be willing to work with you. Especially smaller organizations like churches, or local educational, etc.